# IP addresses using Nginx stream and ELB

Tags: node.js, nginx, amazon-elb

We have an Elastic Load Balancer that uses TCP for 443 and have nginx with the following configuration:

```
stream {
        upstream https_stream {
          hash $remote_addr;
          server 127.0.0.1:8000;
          server 127.0.0.1:8001;
        }
        server {
          listen 443;
          proxy_pass https_stream;
        }
}
```

We need to use TCP because of the way we dynamically handle our SSL certs in nodejs, which are the underlaying servers.  The IP we receive in `req.ip` (using express) is `::ffff:127.0.0.1`.  I don't see any `X-Forwarded-For` header.

Any idea how to get the actual client IP?

Comment: Try adding `real_ip_header X-Forwarded-For;` and 
`set_real_ip_from 0.0.0.0/0;` also to your config, that should get the IP

Comment: These don't work in streams, but also I believe it has to do with `proxy_protocol`, since this is via TCP.  `X-Forwarded-For` actually won't be available.  That being said, configuring Proxy Protocol policy and using `proxy_protocol on` doesn't seem to work.

Comment: I think you could follow this guide https://www.nginx.com/resources/admin-guide/proxy-protocol/